# Lynda - Up and Running with ASP.NET somee.com upload error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, somee

After watching very carefully the guide referenced above (Lynda Up and Running with ASP.NET) , i decided to upload the whole solution to a free host.

Then i found the link below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twNL43W9FRs

Everything went just fine (from the asp.net mvc side of the project), until i used the link that uses database communication. Since then i can't catch a break. The only message i receive is "Error error occurred while processing your request". I believe something is wrong about to connection between the controller and the database or the setup of the database.

Can anyone help me please? It's quite frustrating and i am new to asp.net.

my web.config is below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's impossible to troubleshoot your specific issue with the information you have provided, but I **highly doubt** that you can use `(LocalDb)` for a database on a hosting provider.  It appears, however, that the hosting provider does offer a Free MS SQL database with their free hosting plans; you'll probably want to get the connection string for your database from them.

Comment: You have to see Event viewer for error details .. Do you have access?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use LocalDb on Somee free subscription. You have to use your SQL database provided by them. You will need to create it in control panel, and then change your connection string, so it will point to this database. Something like this:

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=HERE_GOES_DATABASE;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953;Integrated Security=True"
```

Do not worry - they will provide you proper connection string.